# illustrator cs6 when exporting to PDF and print - the black area of masks shown in a low opacity also in PDF preview

Tags: adobe-illustrator, pdf

When I save an illustrator file to pdf (press) that includes a mask
and view the PDF preview or print the file, the black areas of the mask are shown in low opacity.

What's causing this?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

When using masks, especially opacity masks, in Illustrator it is important to use the **proper black** as opposed to just "black". I assume you're using an opacity mask and not a clipping mask, since this issue wouldn't show itself in a clipping mask. Although, based on your sample, a clipping mask would certainly work and be a bit easier.

For **Opacity Masks**, if you use just "black" (the black swatch) - that is a rich RGB black (generally R35G35B35 or close to that) or 100%k, you aren't actually masking everything. You are only masking *those* colors.

This is one instance where using the **"Registration"** swatch *actually* helps. The `Registration` swatch is a swatch which contains the total limit for the color mode. So in RGB, the `Registration` swatch is R0G0B0. In CMYK the `Registration` swatch is 100C100M100Y100K. You **want** the "black" of the mask to be 100% of all colors. You *want* to use the `Registration` swatch rather than the `Black` swatch.

For example... a CMYK image with an opacity mask...
[image]

Note how only the actual black is hidden in the top image. That's because the mask only has 100%K in it. Once you add the other colors, the mask hides those colors as well.

I *do realize* that in print design you are taught to NEVER use 100% of all colors and in fact be mindful of ink limits above 300. However, realize this is a ***mask*** and *not* printed ink. You aren't applying a color to anything to be printed, you are *hiding* the colors in the documents. It's different.

I would *speculate* that your particular opacity mask is using a CMYk Rich black and that is why it's only partially hiding the colors. Bumping the "black" of *your mask object* to 100% for all colors should correct the issue.

If you are working on an RGB image, your mask "black" should be R0G0B0 not any other value.