# How can i trim the artwork

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color, shapes

I have this tree shape artwork and i want to trim hole (which are spotted with black color). I tried with all the trim options, Did not work.
How can i trim. Any other way or option

[File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qjEp-3dyvqJSyAC8ivlnk8bKEl6zmx6F/view?usp=sharing)

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the circles are on top of everything else...

- Select all the circles
- Choose `Object > Compound Path > Make` from the menu. This forces Illustrator to see the circles as one, singular object, rather than a collection of objects.
- Change the **Fill** of the circles to be either 100C100M100Y100K or 0R0G0B, depending upon the color mode you are working in. (Yes, 100% of all inks in CMYK - it's for a *mask* not printed objects.)
- Select all the artwork (trees and circles)
- On the **Transparency Panel** (`Window > Transparency`) click the `Make Mask` button
- **Untick** the `Clip` button on the **Transparency Panel**

This will give you an **Opacity Mask** which will "punch" out the holes in the underlying artwork.

[image]

More on opacity masks...

- [Opacity Mask With Multiple Images (Illustrator CS5)](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/6436/opacity-mask-with-multiple-images-illustrator-cs5)
- [Using the Opacity Mask on Illustrator](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/126822/using-the-opacity-mask-on-illustrator)
- [Why doesn't my opacity mask fully hide my object?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/64083/why-doesnt-my-opacity-mask-fully-hide-my-object)
- [Illustrator: Opacity Mask is not moving/resizing along with object it masks, if the masked object is a Mesh object](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/137123/illustrator-opacity-mask-is-not-moving-resizing-along-with-object-it-masks-if)
- [How to create a gradient opacity mask in Illustrator](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/71406/how-to-create-a-gradient-opacity-mask-in-illustrator)
- [Feather Clipping Mask in Adobe Illustrator](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/153943/feather-clipping-mask-in-adobe-illustrator)
- [illustrator cs6 when exporting to PDF and print - the black area of masks shown in a low opacity also in PDF preview](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/54367/illustrator-cs6-when-exporting-to-pdf-and-print-the-black-area-of-masks-shown)

Answer (score 0):

Definitely what Scott said, but depending on your end purpose, it may actually be easier and quicker to just edit the circles from a black fill, to a white fill.