# How can I cut out all white stripes from black shape?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I am trying to cut out all white stripes from black shape, but Object -> Path -> Divide object below doesn't work. Stripes and shape are on different layers. It is a way to casually erase all stripes, but I'm looking for smth another...

[image]

I was not able to find any detailed documentation or up-to-date answers, so... Please help me if you can <3

Comment: Hi. Why do you want to cut out the white stripes?  Do you know that white is generally non-printing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be aware that many shape operations involving more than 1 object simply won't work across layers. Shape operations typically *require* that all objects be on the *same* layer. In some instances, performing some operations (such as grouping) will *move* objects between layers so the result is all on one layer.

The result below will *move* everything to the topmost layer.

---

The art I used is just a black shape with paths on top that have a white stroke. Everything is an individual object, i.e. nothing is grouped. The paths with white strokes are on a layer above a layer containing the black shape.

- Select all
- `Object > Expand Appearance` (If it's available)
- `Object > Expand` (Turns strokes into shapes)
- `Object > Compound Path > Make`

[image]

This compound shape is now on the topmost layer, where the white strokes were located.

You **may** need to then clean up bits where the white extended outside the black area. Select the shape and grab the **Shape Builder Tool** from the toolbar. Holding down the <kbd>Option/Alt</kbd> just click any bits that extend outside the shape....

[image]

---

If you require the stroked paths to remain stroked paths, as opposed to expanding them, an *Opacity Mask* may work better. It's not possible to create a compound shape with strokes.

See here: [How can i trim the artwork](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/157005/how-can-i-trim-the-artwork)